# Convert HH:MM NSString to NSInteger with minutes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I have several `NSStrings` that contains time duration, they look like that: `@"03:40", @"08:40"` - the time is duration of an action.
I want to have an `int` for each string with minutes, say "01:20" is "80" (minutes) to later compare them with one another.

How do you manage this simple thing in Objective-C?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Tried this, no avail. I want a totally different approach, something easy and light.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)sortResultsByTime
{
    NSMutableArray *sortedTrips = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[_tweets sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id trip1, id trip2) {

        double time1 = [self durationFromString:[(Tweet *) trip1 flightDuration]];
        double time2 = [self durationFromString:[(Tweet *) trip1 flightDuration]];
        NSLog(@"What's time1? It's %f", time1);
        NSLog(@"What's time2? It's %f", time2);

        if (time1 < time2) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }

        if (time1 > time2) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        }

        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }]];

    return sortedTrips;
}

- (double)durationFromString:(NSString *)durationString
{
    NSArray *durationArray = [durationString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

    return [durationArray[0] doubleValue] + [durationArray[1] doubleValue] / 60.0;
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @H2CO3 answered your question. Also the answer has nothing to do with my question, I need a different approach

Comment: Why do you need to convert to ints in order to compare? If your strings have leading zeros you can just use them.

Comment: Also, why all the superfluous casts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is attempting to convert the string to the number of hours, not the number of minutes.

You want:

```
return [durationArray[0] doubleValue] * 60 + [durationArray[1] doubleValue];
```

Edit: The original code is failing because this line:

```
double time2 = [self durationFromString:[(Tweet *) trip1 flightDuration]];
```

needs to be:

```
double time2 = [self durationFromString:[(Tweet *) trip2 flightDuration]];
```

Update: Since the OP wants a different approach why not simply do this:

```
NSString *time1 = [(Tweet *) trip1 flightDuration];
NSString *time2 = [(Tweet *) trip2 flightDuration];

return [time1 compare:time2];
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, but I want a different approach. The stuff with doubleValue doesn't work for me this well.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Converting to double and all this stuff. I want to have raw data in minutes from the number of hours. Without new arrays and overcomplicated techniques.

Comment: How else do you expect to convert a time string to the number of minutes without the need to parse the string? BTW - see my updated answer. You have a trivial typo in your code causing the problem.

Comment: I know, changed that, but Xcode is giving me this on NSLog "What's time1? It's 0.050000"

Comment: Add a log of the original time string so you know for sure what you are converting.

Comment: Add an update to your question with the working code for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Split by `:` (using `-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]`), access each element (with `-[NSArray objectAtIndex:`), then convert to integer (`-[NSString intValue]`) and finally multiply and add.

Comment: Isn't this what is already being done (other than using double instead of integer)?

Comment: Sure it was. I answered before you and I referenced his code.

Comment: It seems very important to you, so I'll explain it. 

When I started answering there wasn't any code in the question. Looking at the date and time of the question (edited) and my answer there is a 2 minutes gap or something like that. I guess I got distracted 2 minutes until I actually hit 'Post' and the code was added in the meanwhile. Did I miss the warning about the question being updated? It sounds plausible. 

I don't remember you looking over my shoulder so don't call me a liar w/out a reason.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you consider other answers overcomplicated, but if you want a solution without arrays, here you are:

```
- (double)durationFromString:(NSString *)s
{
    int hr = 0, min = 0;
    NSScanner *scn = [NSScanner scannerWithString:s];
    [scn scanInt:&hr];
    [scn scanString:@":" intoString:NULL];
    [scn scanInt:&min];
    return hr * 60 + min;
}
```